# How to Use Select top 1 sub query with Left join in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to execute this query but it does not work.Kindly Help me for this solution i want to select top 1 image against related post from sub query with left join

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblAdvertisement.AdvID, 
                tblAdvertisement.CityName, 
                tblAdvertisement.Model, 
                tblAdvertisement.Year, 
                tblAdvertisement.Mileage, 
                tblAdvertisement.imgPath, 
                tblAdvertisement.Price, 
                tblAdvertisement.VoteScore, 
                tblLike.isLike 
FROM            tblAdvertisement 
LEFT JOIN       tblimg 
                ( 
                       SELECT TOP 1 
                              ImgPath 
                       FROM   tblimg ) AS 
ON              tblAdvertisement.AdvID = tblimg.AdvID 
LEFT JOIN       tblLike 
ON              tblAdvertisement.AdvID = tblLike.AdvID 
AND             tblAdvertisement.UserID = @userID 
ORDER BY        AdvID DESC
```

Comment: You should search about `OUTER APPLY`

Comment: A Nice [article on Cross/outer Apply](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607246/Making-OUTER-and-CROSS-APPLY-work-for-you) from codeproject.

Comment: That joined subquery should have the aliasname after that AS, not before the subquery. It can be either a LEFT JOIN ON (1=1) or an OUTER APPLY.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.AdvID, 
                A.CityName, 
                A.Model, 
                A.Year, 
                A.Mileage, 
                I.imgPath, 
                A.Price, 
                A.VoteScore, 
                L.isLike 
FROM            tblAdvertisement A
OUTER APPLY     ( SELECT TOP 1 
                              ImgPath 
                  FROM   tblimg
                  WHERE  AdvID = A.AdvID
                  ORDER BY SomeColumnToOrderBy) I
LEFT JOIN       tblLike L
ON              A.AdvID = L.AdvID 
AND             A.UserID = @userID 
ORDER BY        A.AdvID DESC;
```

Please notice that if you need the `TOP 1` image, you should be doing an `ORDER BY`, otherwise you would be getting some arbitrary row instead of the one you actually want.